# CURL cross compiling

Tags: ubuntu, curl, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

i am cross compiling Curl Library for ARM processor on ubuntu, getting following error while runing make command.
error "strerror_r MUST be either POSIX, glibc or vxworks-style"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that configure failed to detect your `strerror_r` version (which is a bit odd if you're doing this for a Linux) so you can define it manually in `lib/curl_config.h` afterwards:

```
/* Define to 1 if you have a working POSIX-style strerror_r function. */
#define HAVE_POSIX_STRERROR_R 1
```

Comment: of course I now realize you tagged it 'cmake', which could then be another reason for the failure and I think you should switch to using configure instead...

Comment: Seeing that you are the developer, it also happened with me while compiling on 2.6.32 ARMv5tel device. Thing is indeed included in cmake ;-). I set it to POSIX as you indicated here, but that is probably wrong lol.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that curl's CMake tests available **libc** functions by [CMake command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/try_run.html) `try_run`. But this command generates binaries that can't be executed directly when you crosscompiling. As a result, both variables (`HAVE_GLIBC_STRERROR_R`, `HAVE_POSIX_STRERROR_R`) are false and build fails.

There is simple way how to fix it. Just install `qemu-user` package to emulate binaries for target platform and setup `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING` and `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR` variables.

For example (when you crosscompile for aarch64):

```
cmake \
  -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=TRUE \
  -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR=/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64 \
  ..
```

...when you use non-standard path for target-platform libraries, you should create emulator shell script and setup path there:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/sh\nexec /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64 -L /altroot/aarch64/ "$@"' > /usr/local/bin/qemu-aarch64-altroot
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/qemu-aarch64-altroot
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add

```
HAVE_POSIX_STRERROR_R
```

flag to cmake while compiling it.

Comment: How does one add any flag to CMake?